# How to create a mobile version on a subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, mobile, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create a mobile version of our application on the subdomain, like **m.website.com**. Our app is written in Ruby on Rails and running on Amazon AWS.

What's the best approach to create and manage it?
The initial though is to "copy" the whole project, put the code to the new git repository, set up the mobile layout, set up the EC2 instance and push it on **m.website.com**.

But the disadvantage is that we would have at the moment 2 applications, in 2 repositories in 2 instances, so maintaining will be quite difficult.

Is there any better way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would have a before filter thing to set the layout I think.  Something along the lines of

```
if request.subdomain.present? and request.subdomain != "www"
   render layout: "mobile"
else
   render layout: "application"
end
```